# Fluent Validation ensure child entity is not null best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm developing a full stack webapi on asp.net core 2.0 with entity framework core 2.

I have a question regarding what is the best practise when it comes to data validation on incoming requests.

I have the following class;

```
public class TradeCategory : AuditableEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Language Language { get; set; }
}
```

For my fluent validator, I want to ensure that when an TradeCategory is inserted that the Language associated with it is not null. I also want to ensure that the language is only referenced and not updated.

So, for example, if the following were passed across the following json to my webapi;

```
[{
     Name: "Test Name",
     Value: 5,
     Language {
         Id: 1,
         Name: "Changing the Name"
     }
}]
```

So I want to avoid giving the person posting the ability either insert a new language when adding the TradeCategory, nor do I want them to update an existing language.

I suppose could add change my TradeCategory to be;

```
public class TradeCategory : AuditableEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Language")]
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public Language Language { get; set; }
}
```

But I like the idea of keeping my classes clean. So far I have;

```
    public TradeCategoryValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.Value).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.Language).NotNull()
            .Must(x => x.Id > 0)
            .Must(x => x.Country == null);
    }
```

Should I be overly concerned with this or should I control this at the service level and point of insert? i.e. throw an error if the language is fully populated etc? as if in the example above I post to EF with the child entity will update all the Language details as well as the TradeCategory entity (correct me if I am wrong there)?

Thanks

Comment: I usually validate the request model object by writing a extension method with the name 'IsValid()'. When you just want to associate a child entity with the parent, always populate only the foreign key and do not assign the 'entity' to the navigation property. Not sure if it helps, but this is the convention that I follow.

Comment: Ok, so do you use the seperate foreignkey attribute along with the additional int for the foreign key?

Comment: yes, I mark the foreign key property with the attribute